# git-svn clone server sent unexpected return value (303 see other)

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to clone my project on google code svn into a local git repository.

when running `git svn clone http://dobberman.googlecode.com/svn -s dobberman` i get the following error message:

> RA layer request failed: Server sent unexpected return value (303 See
>   Other) in response to OPTIONS request for
>   'http://dobberman.googlecode.com/svn' at /usr/lib/got-core/git-svn
>   line 1923

Anyone familiar with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the message indicates that the repo is no longer there and has moved to a different location.

But if I try `git svn clone http://dobberman.googlecode.com/svn -s dobberman`, everything  works fine... I don't get an error message.

Looking closer shows me that the repo is empty though. Also, `git log` tells me: `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`. Obviously something went wrong here.

`-s` indicates standard repo layout. But the SVN repo has no `/trunk` sub-folder, no `branches` sub-folder and no `tags` folder. I guess this is the reason why there are no revisions. Try removing the `-s` switch and only do a

```
git svn clone http://dobberman.googlecode.com/svn dobberman
```